# To what extent can modern medicine heal this scarring?

Tags: removal, scar-tissue-scars

Here is some rather extensive scarring on the forearm from 15 years ago.  Can it be healed by modern medicine (even if it is expensive), and to what extent?  What methods are there to deal with it (skin grafts, etc.)?

Please note that this is not a request for personal medical advice, but on the state of modern medicine in dealing with scar removal.

[image: scarring]